# CPU max MHz showing below base clock

Tags: cpu, intel, lscpu

I have a lenovo thinkpad e15 with a i7-10510U with baseclock of 1.80GHz when I run
`lscpu | grep CPU` it shows.

```
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
CPU family:                      6
CPU max MHz:                     800.0000
CPU min MHz:                     400.0000
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-7
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
```

Max cpu is only 800 and my pc has been running slow, does anyone have any recommendation on how to fix this.

Update: Running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Changing Ubuntu Power settings seems to have no effect.

Update: enabling intel speedstep in the bios how has the correct max frequency. Laptop is till running moslty at 0.4GHz and all tasks are slowed down, unresponsive mouse movement, delayed typing etc.

Comment: Which Linux distro are you running? And have you checked energy settings already? This seems to be the result of energy saving mode but it can be any number of things. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I have checked anywhere I can think and its set to performance.
Running ```cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```
showed powersaving but updating that to performance did not seem to fix anything.

Comment: 1. Again, please [edit] the question to add relevant information asked about in comments. This is the purpose of comments, not to add info that should be in the question itself. 2. Perhaps you shouldn't be messing with that? In Ubuntu you should select the mode (balanced) in system settings, energy, then restart and test again.

Answer (score -1):

CPU's can operate at several different frequencies changing dynamically under the load
the "**CPU max MHz**" value is the maximum frequency used by your most cpu consuming task it's not the limit of your cpu at all.

run `yes > /dev/null &` multiple times (4x in my case) until you reach 100% cpu usage
you can check it by running `top` then re run `lscpu | grep CPU` you should get higher speed

make sure to kill background jobs

about your system slowing down you need to provide more information like what is the task that got slowed down